# how to overcome this NullPointerException?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, nullpointerexception, prepared-statement

```
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.io.*; 
    import java.util.*;


    public class A {


        public static void main(String args[]){

        try {


            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:debjeet", "system", "tiger");
        PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("insert into emp values('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')"); //there are 17 fields in the database
        BufferedReader dis= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter the desired username");
        String us=dis.readLine();
        st.setString(1,(String)us); //this was an attempt made by me to remove the exception ,otherwise all were below as from index 4.also the exception occurs here.
        System.out.println("Enter the desired password");
        String pw=dis.readLine();
        st.setString(2,pw);
        System.out.println("Enter your First Name");
        String fn=dis.readLine();
        st.setString(3, fn);

        System.out.println("Enter your Middle Name");
        String mn=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Last Name");
        String ln=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Email");
        String em=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Date of Birth");
        int dob= Integer.parseInt(dis.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your Month of Birth");
        String mob=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Year of Birth");
        int yob=Integer.parseInt(dis.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your Gender(M/F)");
        String gen=dis.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter your Institute");
        String inst=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Address");
        String add=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your City");
        String ct=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your State");
        String state=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your Pincode");
        int pin=Integer.parseInt(dis.readLine());
        System.out.println("Enter your Country");
        String cn=dis.readLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your 10 digit mobile number");
        String phnum=dis.readLine();

        System.out.println("Thank you :D");

             st.setString(4, mn);

        st.setString(5, ln);

        st.setString(6, em);

        st.setString(7, gen);

        st.setString(8, inst);

        st.setString(9, add);

        st.setString(10, ct);

        st.setString(11, state);

        st.setInt(12, pin);

        st.setString(13, cn);

        st.setString(14, phnum);

        st.setInt(15,dob);

        st.setString(16, mob);

        st.setInt(17, yob);

        int i=st.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);


}
}
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter the desired username
grg
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

this code is showing a null pointer exception in a machine and an invalid column index          message in other machine. dont know how to proceed.on the other hand the databse is working fine if am tryin to insert values using a statement object.i guess there is a problem in the prepared statement object but cannot resolve it.

Comment: Start by **not** catching Exception, or at least print its stack trace in the catch block. The stack trace will tell you exactly where the exception happens.

Comment: I have found out.The exception was taking place within the braces where i have typed the '?' marks within ' ' it shall b simply ? followed by commas because java.lang takes this servlet request by default as strings